# Android development: Associate activity with file extension for different API versions

Tags: android, intentfilter, file-extension, file-association

When file location is private for app (Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/) it was recognized.
For API level 30+ file in Downloads folder does not recognized.
I think -intent filter- is correct because it workf for API29 in any folder and for app's private folder in all API versions.
Something goes wrong in Download folder for API30+.

Have any idea how to resolve this problem?

Intent filter for .ImportDatabase activity of com.mydomain.myapp application.

```
<intent-filter
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="Import DB">
    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
    <data android:scheme="file" />
    <data android:scheme="content" />
    <data android:host="*" />
    <data android:mimeType="*/*" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\.ctdb" />
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
    <data android:pathPattern=".*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\..*\\.ctdb"/>
</intent-filter>
```

System events when I click on myapp.ctdb file.

First line of each log for API's - file myapp.ctdb is in private folder (Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/).

Second line - file myapp.ctdb is in Download folder.

Third line - file justcsvfile.csv (comma separated text file, just for test) is in Download folder. *.csv has no viewer or association with any app in this systems.

[OK] - fie is recognized and complete content is returned. .ImportDatabase activity was launched.

[!!] - file is not recognized by system.

```
Targer SDK 31, compile SDK 31
API 29
[OK] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/myapp.ctdb typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3 cmp=com.mydomain.myapp/.ImportDatabase} from uid 10057
[OK] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/myapp.ctdb typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x3 cmp=com.mydomain.myapp/.ImportDatabase} from uid 10057
[OK] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/justcsvfile.csv typ=text/comma-separated-values flg=0x3} from uid 10057
API 30
[OK] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/myapp.ctdb typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x20000003 cmp=com.mydomain.myapp/.ImportDatabase} from uid 10071
[!!] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:27 typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x20000003} from uid 10071
[!!] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:28 typ=text/comma-separated-values flg=0x20000003} from uid 10071
API 31
[OK] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.externalstorage.documents/document/primary:Android/data/com.mydomain.myapp/files/myapp.ctdb typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x20000003 cmp=com.mydomain.myapp/.ImportDatabase} from uid 10071
[!!] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/msf:29 typ=application/octet-stream flg=0x20000003} from uid 10071
[OK] I/ActivityTaskManager: START u0 {act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.providers.downloads.documents/document/raw:/storage/emulated/0/Download/justcsvfile.csv typ=text/comma-separated-values flg=0x20000003} from uid 10071
```

Comment: `pathPattern` is generally useless for `content`, as there is no requirement for a `content` `Uri` to have anything particular in its path, such as a file extension. If you need to handle some widely-recognized MIME type, such as `text/comma-separated-values`, use an `<intent-filter>` for that MIME type. Otherwise, an `<intent-filter>` is likely to have limited effect, and your app will need to use other approaches (e.g., `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`).

Comment: @CommonsWare thanks for comment. I want handle custom extension *.ctdb in Downloads folder. I will try ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT.

Comment: @CommonsWare click on file alwais fires system android.intent.action.VIEW. Without pathPattern it not works where works before. Main task is recognize files in Download foldef for API30+